# How do I pass a change in an input number field properly to trigger a change in the ngModel?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button that opens a dialog box (MatDialog). This dialog allows the user to select values in a clock face. I perform a calculation that returns a number. When the user closes the dialog, the number is returned to the original parent and updates a numeric input field. This input field is utilized in calculating another field on the view. When I click the up/down arrows, the calculated field gets updates. When I update the value from the dialog, the calculation is not triggered. I am wondering if it is because it is outside the Angular Zone?

I have tried using triggering events from jQuery. I have also tried implementations of NgModelChange and Directives. I am thinking that Directives might be the way to go but I am not sure I did it correctly.

```
// numeric input field from the view
<input class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" placeholder="0.00" (change)="onRecordUpdated(timeCard, timecarddet)" name="hoursWorked" id="hoursWorked" [(ngModel)]="timecarddet.hours" min="0" max="365" #hoursWorked>
```

```
// Dialog box code that runs when the end user clicks the close button
// calcHours function to calculate the hours worked when the clock dialog is used
  public calcHours (): void {
    // Variables to capture timeClock entries from DOM. Total variable to house calculation
    let currentStartTime = this.elStartTime.nativeElement.value;
    let currentStopTime = this.elStopTime.nativeElement.value;
    // Cast the returned time from string to number
    currentStartTime = +( currentStartTime.slice( 0, -( currentStartTime.indexOf( ':' ) + 1 ) ) );
    currentStopTime = +( currentStopTime.slice( 0, -( currentStopTime.indexOf( ':' ) + 1 ) ) );
    // Math to calculate the number of hours based upon the returned string time
    const totalHours = currentStopTime - currentStartTime;
    if ( currentStartTime !== '' && currentStopTime !== '' ) {
      this.dialogRef.close( totalHours );
    }
  }
```

```
// Parent code that runs after the dialog is closed
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( result => {
      // Value returned from dialog box
      const dialogHoursCalc = `${ result }`;
      // Set value of input field from dialog box
      // this.renderer.setProperty( this.elHoursWorked.nativeElement, 'value', dialogHoursCalc );
      // Tried using jQuery instead of renderer
      $( '#hoursWorked' ).val( dialogHoursCalc );
      $( '#hoursWorked' ).trigger( 'change' );
    } );
```

```
// Pay field that is calculated using the hours from the hoursWorked field
<input type="number" class="form-control" data-number-to-fixed="2" [(ngModel)]="timecarddet.earnings" readonly="true" id="c2" disabled>
```

I want the numeric input field changed with the calculation from the dialog and then the calculation for the pay performed in the same manner as if someone were to manually update the field directly.

***EDIT***
Here is the directive route I tried...

```
/// Directive
import { Directive, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[appHoursWorked]' })

export class HoursWorkedDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);

  constructor(
    private _el: ElementRef,
    private _ngZone: NgZone
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this._ngZone.run(() =>
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this._el.nativeElement.value));
  }
}
```

I put the selector as an attribute on the input. I imported the directive into the app module and declared the directive. When I did that, I received the following error...

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that the timecarddet object does not get updated. Do I need to implement ngOnChanges?

Comment: Clay, not use jQuery. when you has a mat-dialog, you can open a component. If this component has a button with the directive [mat-dialog-close] you can use this to give the value, e.g. `<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal"`. See the docs. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Thank you, Eliseo. I have the dialog returning the value. What I am struggling with is getting the change event to fire when I update the numeric input.

Comment: I believe I have discovered the problem. I was using a template-based form and the value was being mutated outside the Angular change detection process. I am switching to Reactive Forms.